# Pass a variable from a Custom Filter to controller action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I have a Web Api project.

I have implemented a custom Authentication Attribute like so:

```
public class TokenAuthenticationAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // In auth web method you should implement functionality of authentication
        // so that client app could be able to get token
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("api/auth/login"))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Receive token from the client. Here is the example when token is in header:
        var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Token"];

        // Put your secret key into the configuration
        var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTSecurityKey"];

        try
        {
            string jsonPayload = JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secretKey);

            int separatorIndex = jsonPayload.IndexOf(';');

            string userId = "";
            DateTime timeIssued = DateTime.MinValue;

            if (separatorIndex >= 0)
            {
                //userId = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(jsonPayload.Substring(0, separatorIndex)));
                userId = jsonPayload.Substring(0, separatorIndex);
                timeIssued = DateTime.Parse(jsonPayload.Substring(separatorIndex + 1));
            }

            short TokenTTL = 10;
            //try{
            //Int16.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenTTL"],TokenTTL);
            //}catch(Exception e){           //}

            if ((DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeIssued).TotalMinutes >= TokenTTL))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }

            //Save user in context                
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
              {
                   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userId)
              };
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { id });

            actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;

        }
        catch (JWT.SignatureVerificationException)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I get hold of that user in my actionmethod?

```
[BasicHttpAuthorizeAttribute]
[httpGet]
public void Login()
{
 // how do i get user here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> /////// Save the string username  to the context so that I can acess
>   it in the controler.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "john")
};
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { id });
actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;
```

> // how do i get user here

```
var name = User.Identity.Name;
```

BTW, use an authentication filter instead of an authorization filter to perform authentication. See my blog post - http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-using-authentication-filter/.

Comment: I am getting and error: in the last line, `.GetRequestContext()` is underlined red. (does not contain a definition for 'getrequestcontex'`

Comment: I am using this to validate a JWT token on every request. Will a authentication filter still work for this?

Comment: Add this directive to the TokenAuthenticationAttribute class - `using System.Net.Http;`

Comment: You should use authentication filter for authenticating all sorts of credential.

Comment: Also how can I skip the authentication precess. for example I dont want it to authenticate when I go to auth/login

Comment: @Bandri How do I exclude a controller from being authenticated? I have implemented your solution and I cannot figure out how to exclude a controller, such as my login controller. [allowAnnonmous] does work.